# Non-model based serialization in Wagtail API response

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-apiv2

I'm retrieving a list of pages via a custom API endpoint called `sitemap`. The goal of this endpoint is to return *just* the URL and last_updated flag so that I can generate a sitemap.xml file for my website. I can't apply a custom serializer to the model as I don't want to affect the normal pages API endpoint we're using.

Is it possible to apply a serializer to an API queryset rather than serializing it at the model level?

I could probably do this with a list comprehension, but a custom serializer feels like a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it's *much* easier than I thought. I created a custom serializer:

```
class SitemapSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    page_name = serializers.CharField()
    url_slug = serializers.CharField()
```

Then applied that serializer to my APIEndpoint class:

```
class SitemapPagesAPIEndpoint(PagesAPIEndpoint):
    base_serializer_class = SitemapSerializer
```

I think the thing that threw me off was that the property wasn't called `serializer_class`.